# error: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘memcpy’ [enabled by default]

Tags: c, memcpy

I get this error.

```
error: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘memcpy’ [enabled by default]
```

This is the code:

```
int arr[ 12] = {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,9370, 0};
void *a = &arr;
memcpy(machine->mem, a,12*4);
```

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 114, accepted):

You likely forgot to include `<string.h>`.

Add `#include <string.h>` to the top of your file.